# monotouch push notification

Tags: xamarin.ios, push, apple-push-notifications

Does anyone know why the following method within my app would receive a null deviceToken after registering with APNS (with MonoTouch)?

public override void RegisteredForRemoteNotifications (UIApplication application,  NSData deviceToken){
     //
}

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The debugger says that the deviceToken is null but it is not.  (At least that is what I observe)  You can use the code below to build a string that represents your device token.

```cs
public override void RegisteredForRemoteNotifications (UIApplication application, NSData deviceToken)
{
    byte [] token = deviceToken.ToArray ();
    string tokenString = "";

    for (int i=0; i<deviceToken.Length; i++)
        tokenString += token[i].ToString ("X2");

    Console.WriteLine (tokenString);
}
```

[Here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-12) is a good tutorial that explains push notifications.  It is for XCode but it is easy to convert.